# GRUB missing Window option after update

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, grub, windows-update

After Windows update yesterday, my PC which initially dual boot with Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, has a missing "Windows" option upon the GRUB start up.

I had tried to repair the PC with bootable Windows 10 USB stick, still the same.

Currently I can only boot into Ubuntu.

In there, Ubuntu partition setting there, could see the Windows 10 sit safe and sound. The problem is that it's just missing in the GRUB start up.

Answer (score 0):

**No, you still can boot Windows directly in UEFI settings > Boot.**

So, do that, let it finish any pending updates, reboot and disable again Fast Startup (likely re-enabled by the feature update).

Shutdown.

Again at UEFI settings > Boot change it back to "Ubuntu".

Boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`. This should re-detect Windows and restore the Grub menu entries as before.